# setting state variable to a given value using ode15s

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm using ode15s to simulate/solve a set of ODEs. I would like to implement a feature, where upon reaching a given condition during the simulation, a number in the model changes programatically (e.g., an indicator constant) for a fixed amount of time, and then reverts back.

This could be, for example using Lotka-Volterra equations:

dx/dt = alpha*x - beta*x*y

dy/dt = (delta+indicator)*x*y - gamma*y + epsilon*indicator

indicator starts as 0. Let's say that when x reaches 10, I'd like to switch indicator to 1 for 10 time units, and then flip it back to 0.

This can be done in a dirty way by using global variables, however, this is something I'd like to avoid (impossible to parallelize + general avoidance of global variables). Is there a neat alternative way when using ode15s (i.e., I don't know the time step)?

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** As noted correctly by [LutzL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3088138/lutzl), wrapping an ODE with non-smooth state without handling events may lead to inaccurate results

> as you can not predict at what time points in what order the ODE
>   function is evaluated. [LutzL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3088138/lutzl)

So the accurate solution is to deal with [ODE events](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html). An example for the modified Lotka-Volterra equations is given below, where the event fires, if `x` gets >10 and the indicator will be turned on for 10 seconds:

```
% parameters and times:
params = ones(5,1); % [alpha, ..., epsilon]
z_start = [2, 1];
t_start = 0;
t_end = 30;

options = odeset('Events',@LotkaVolterraModEvents); % set further options here, too.

% wrap ODE function with indicator on and off
LVModODE_indicatorOn = @(t,z)LotkaVolterraModODE(t,z,1, params);
LVModODE_indicatorOff = @(t,z)LotkaVolterraModODE(t,z,0, params);

% storage for simulation values:
data.t = t_start;
data.z = z_start;
data.teout = [];
data.zeout = zeros(0,2);
data.ieout = [];

% temporary loop variables:
z_0 = z_start;
t_0 = t_start;
isIndicatorActive = false;

while data.t(end) < t_end % until the end time is reached
    if isIndicatorActive
        % integrate for 10 seconds, if indicator is active
        active_seconds = 10;
        [t, z, te,ze,ie] = ode15s(LVModODE_indicatorOn, [t_0 t_0+active_seconds], z_0, options);
    else
        % integrate until end or event, if indicator is not active.
        [t, z, te,ze,ie] = ode15s(LVModODE_indicatorOff, [t_0 t_end], z_0, options);
        isIndicatorActive = true;
    end

    %append data to storage
    t_len = length(t);
    data.t = [data.t; t(2:end)];
    data.z = [data.z; z(2:end,:)];
    data.teout = [data.teout; te];
    data.zeout = [data.zeout; ze];
    data.ieout = [data.ieout; ie];

    % reinitialize start values for next iteration of loop
    t_0 = t(end);
    z_0 = z(end, :);

    % set the length of the last instegration
    options = odeset(options,'InitialStep',t(end) - t(end-1));
end

%% plot your results:
figure;
plot(data.t, data.z(:,1), data.t, data.z(:,2));
hold all
plot(data.teout, data.zeout(:,1), 'ok');
legend('x','y', 'Events in x')

%% Function definitions for integration and events:
function z_dot = LotkaVolterraModODE(t, z, indicator, params)
    x = z(1); y= z(2);
    % state equations: modified Lotka-Volterra system
             z_dot =  [params(1)*x - params(2)*y;
                       (params(4) + indicator)*x*y - params(3)*y + params(5)*indicator];
end

function [value, isTerminal, direction] = LotkaVolterraModEvents(t,z)
    x = z(1);
    value = x-10; % event on rising edge when x passes 10
    isTerminal = 1; %stop integration -> has to be reinitialized from outer logic
    direction = 1; % only event on rising edge (i.e. x(t_e-)<10 and x(t_e+)>10)
end
```

The main work is done in the `while` loop, where the integration takes place.

---

**(Old post)** The following solution may lead to inaccurate results, handling events, as explained in the first part should be preferred.

You could wrap your problem in a class, which is able to hold a state (i.e. its properties). The class should have a method, which is used as `odefun` for the variable-step integrator. See also [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html) on how to write classes in MATLAB.

The example below demonstrates, how it could be achieved for the example you provided:

```
% file: MyLotkaVolterra.m
classdef MyLotkaVolterra < handle
    properties(SetAccess=private)
        %define, if the modified equation is active
        indicator; 

        % define the start time, where the condition turned active.
        tStart; 

        % ode parameters [alpha, ..., epsilon]
        params;
    end

    methods
        function self = MyLotkaVolterra(alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon)
            self.indicator = 0;
            self.tStart = 0;
            self.params = [alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon];
        end

        % ODE funciton for the state z = [x;y] and time t
        function z_dot = odefun(self, t, z)
             x = z(1); y= z(2);
             if (x>=10 && ~self.indicator)
                 self.indicator = 1;
                 self.tStart = t;
             end

             %condition to turn indicator off:
             if (self.indicator && t - self.tStart >= 10)
                self.indicator = false; 
             end

             % state equations: modified Lotka-Volterra system
             z_dot =  [self.params(1)*x - self.params(2)*y;
                       (self.params(4) + self.indicator)*x*y - ...
                        self.params(3)*y + self.params(5)*self.indicator];
        end
    end
end
```

This class could be used as follows:

```
% your ode using code:
% 1. create an object (`lvObj`) from the class with parameters alpha = ... = epsilon = 1
lvObj = MyLotkaVolterra(1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
% 2. pass its `odefun`method to the integrator (exaple call with ode15s)
[t,y] = ode15s(@lvObj.odefun, [0,5], [9;1]); % 5 seconds
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I was thinking how to hack it together with ode events that it didn't occur to me there is a neat way like this. Or maybe a nested function (which can see the parent's variables) could do. I'll experiment and see, but thanks again for pointing this out.

Comment: This is quite unreliable, as you can not predict at what time points in what order the ODE function is evaluated. At least the maximum time step should be set to something reasonably small. For such non-smooth state/control changes it is best to use some kind of event mechanism.